# Using key/Value of a key as reference to OrderByChild to filter certain items only on Android Studio Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, shopping-cart

I am trying to make an e-commerce app. When making the AddToCart.class I made a copy of an intended item from a registered item into the Cart node of the current user. Then I populate the Cart fragment with the cart node.

The problem with this is that. When the seller updates the item. the item in the cart node does not update as it is a copy of the pre-updated item.

So, instead of copying the whole object. Instead, I populate the Cart node with only the key to the intended item.

These are the Json for my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
{
  "User": {
    "AtCw45nJ7TTqb12MLtVOEurlUj62": {
      "Cart": {
        "-NOLDZyNHqm_FPJxHEil": "-NOLDZyNHqm_FPJxHEil",
        "-NOxdW2dIG5H3RBNHffN": "-NOxdW2dIG5H3RBNHffN"
      },
      "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
      "name": "kii",
      "password": "123123",
      "student": "123231"
    },
    "Azml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2": {
      "Cart": {
        "-NO8sKBA80OS9yPWQ3AC": "-NO8sKBA80OS9yPWQ3AC",
        "-NO8tmPEwYZtm_t8CQm2": "-NO8tmPEwYZtm_t8CQm2"
      },
      "Inventory": {
        "-NOLDZyNHqm_FPJxHEil": {
          "cat": "Food",
          "description": "123123",
          "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fyp2-7b907.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FAzml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2%2FAzml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2%2FThu%20Feb%2016%2001%3A58%3A20%20GMT%2B08%3A00%202023?alt=media&token=8b6c2e19-9384-4237-a64b-0a8840a87c20",
          "item_name": "dratini",
          "price": "222",
          "user": "Azml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2"
        },
        "-NOxdW2dIG5H3RBNHffN": {
          "cat": "Food",
          "description": "qwe",
          "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fyp2-7b907.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FAzml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2%2FAzml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2%2FTue%20Feb%2028%2017%3A29%3A38%20GMT%2B08%3A00%202023?alt=media&token=802b6e47-2b6d-46f7-b0d8-7d96c230e5f9",
          "item_name": "axew",
          "price": "222",
          "user": "Azml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2"
        },
        "-NPMN1s0mgQ3MIbaPHua": {
          "cat": "Clothing",
          "description": "123",
          "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fyp2-7b907.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FAzml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2%2FAzml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2%2FTue%20Feb%2028%2017%3A35%3A05%20GMT%2B08%3A00%202023?alt=media&token=82e27e63-5315-4770-90bd-6704fe47da69",
          "item_name": "starly",
          "price": "123",
          "user": "Azml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2"
        }
      },
      "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
      "name": "miki",
      "password": "123123",
      "student": "58708"
    },
    "X3kEec1ivKXfBTf4jGBWUFHeHht2": {
      "Inventory": {
        "-NO8sKBA80OS9yPWQ3AC": {
          "cat": "Food",
          "description": "edited New",
          "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fyp2-7b907.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FX3kEec1ivKXfBTf4jGBWUFHeHht2%2FX3kEec1ivKXfBTf4jGBWUFHeHht2%2FTue%20Feb%2014%2015%3A27%3A20%20GMT%2B05%3A00%202023?alt=media&token=370ccb93-ce54-49bb-90a7-eb8a2e7045dc",
          "item_name": "axsweNEW",
          "price": "222",
          "user": "X3kEec1ivKXfBTf4jGBWUFHeHht2"
        },
        "-NO8tmPEwYZtm_t8CQm2": {
          "cat": "Food",
          "description": "asdasdEdied",
          "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fyp2-7b907.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FX3kEec1ivKXfBTf4jGBWUFHeHht2%2FX3kEec1ivKXfBTf4jGBWUFHeHht2%2FTue%20Feb%2014%2015%3A32%3A28%20GMT%2B05%3A00%202023?alt=media&token=5039441c-f31f-4d4e-aa9f-3bf75b24a4de",
          "item_name": "asdsad",
          "price": "123",
          "user": "X3kEec1ivKXfBTf4jGBWUFHeHht2"
        }
      },
      "email": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      "name": "test",
      "password": "pass123",
      "student": "matric number"
    }
  }
}
```

So Right now my query is as follows, I expecting for the recyclerview to be populated with items from inventory nodes which contain the object of an inventory. and then filter out the items that are not listed in the current user cart.

```
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            String userId = user.getUid();

            DatabaseReference cartref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userId).child("Cart");


            cartref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
 public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                    String CartItemId = snapshot.getKey();
                    DatabaseReference itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Inventory").child(CartItemId);
                    itemRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                CartInventory inventory = childSnapshot.getValue(CartInventory.class);
                                inventory.setKey(childSnapshot.getKey());
                                cartArrayList.add(inventory);
                            }
                            cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

        }
```

after debugging I found out that the snapshot returns a null value at adapter holder.

also I have tried changing this part here

`DatabaseReference itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Inventory").child(CartItemId);`

to `.getReference("User")` but still getting null value

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, what is the reference on which you attach the first listener?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've updated the question as requested

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-firebase-part-1-4f305485e5d2) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireMag).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the second user in your database which has the ID of `Azml0TbC5MfqNdBjZYrOzdhcDhW2`, it indeed has a child called `Cart` but it also has another child called `Inventory`. So the problem comes when you're using the following line of code:

```
DatabaseReference itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Inventory").child(CartItemId);
```

Why? Because the `Inventory` node isn't a child of your root reference but is nested under `User/$uid/Inventory`. So to solve this, you either make the `Inventory` node, a child under the root reference, or you create a reference that points to `User/$uid/Inventory`. But in my opinion, the first solution would be better.

Comment: This is my error for not editing the whole code but, I have tried `DatabaseReference itemRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstances().getReference("User")` and then adding a child listener on itemRef.  But it still returns a null value. I have changing the referecence a lot of times and starting to think that this approach is not possible on android/firebase, or maybe get a hint on where I went wrong for this specific approach.

Comment: also thank you for the link I will make sure to study it thoroughly.

Comment: `DatabaseReference itemRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstances().getReference("User")` doesn't help. Have you tried the first solution in my answer? Simply move those nodes out of the user node, and you can let the code unchanged.

Comment: I import a json which I have altered to have an Inventory node outside from user. Inside the Inventory node I have populate it with one child which is a copy of the item which I want to load into my recyclerview. But the recyclerview is still empty.

Comment: when I debug, child(CartItemId) does provide the correct output, but the view holder is empty

Comment: In that case, most likely you have a problem with the adapter. So I recommend you post a follow-up question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with information regarding the initial question?